# How to create an independent properties panel for bpmn-js in angularjs

Tags: camunda-modeler, bpmn.io

I am new to bpmn & js world :).
So far I manage to create and integrate custom elements and custom properties panel with bpmn-js modeler by following several examples in bpmn.io github projects.

But my requirement is to create a custom properties panel based on angularjs.
So the bpmn-js modeler and my custom properties panel will reside side by side in an 
angularjs app.

My question is how to bind or attach my custom properties with the bpmn-js elements (i.e. start event) in the modeler and to make sure that my custom properties panel will behave exactly same as bpmnjs or camunda properties panel.

Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You can add some code of what you have tried yet so others can create better answers.

Comment: @Jankapunkt Thanks for your comments, I didn't add any code because I actually want to create whole properties panel in angularjs and the code I have may not be relevant, I have followed [link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/properties-panel) and [link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/properties-panel) to create custom properties and [link](https://github.com/bpmn-io/bpmn-js-examples/tree/master/custom-elements) to create custom elements in the pallet.